# Print CatBoost hyperparameters

Tags: python, catboost

How to print CatBoost hyperparameters after training a model?

In `sklearn` we can just print model object that it will show all parameters but in `catboost` it only print object's reference: `<catboost.core.CatBoostRegressor object at 0x7fd441e5f6d8>`.

```py
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor
# Initialize data

train_data = [[1, 4, 5, 6],
              [4, 5, 6, 7],
              [30, 40, 50, 60]]

eval_data = [[2, 4, 6, 8],
             [1, 4, 50, 60]]

train_labels = [10, 20, 30]
# Initialize CatBoostRegressor
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=2,
                          learning_rate=1,
                          depth=2)
# Fit model
model.fit(train_data, train_labels)
# Get predictions
preds = model.predict(eval_data)
print (model)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

print(model.get_params()) should do

Answer (score 0):

Use `print(model.get_all_params())` to print all default parameters.